# how to get ThreadPool,WebContainer,Session,ConnectionPool mbeans in websphere v 8.5.5v liberty profile

Tags: rest, websphere, websphere-liberty

I need to monitor WAS liberty profiles i made some configuration changes in sever.xml

```
<feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>^M
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>^M
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>^M
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>^M
```

but when i am connecting with rest port i am only getting following mbeans regarding websphere

```
WebSphere
WebSphere:feature=restConnector,type=FileService,name=FileService
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=WLProject
WebSphere:feature=channelfw,type=endpoint,name=defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl
WebSphere:feature=restConnector,type=FileTransfer,name=FileTransfer
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=kohls
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.kernel.filemonitor.FileNotificationMBean
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=worklightadmin
WebSphere:feature=channelfw,type=endpoint,name=defaultHttpEndpoint
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=worklightconsole
WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.jmx.mbeans.generatePluginConfig
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=_analytics
WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.config.serverSchemaGenerator
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=_MobileBrowserSimulator
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=nsecom
```

not able to get threadpool, webcontaineer mbeans , is there any configuration i have to do??

Comment: monitor 1.0 feature definition is not found error coming in logs ...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe update to the latest Liberty version and try to test with jconsole. I'm running v8.5.5.3 and it works fine. I'm using the following command to start jconsole using rest connector (all in one line, formatted for readability):

```
jconsole 
    -J-Djava.class.path=C:\
IBM\WebSphere\LibertyIM\java\java_1.7_32\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liber
tyIM\java\java_1.7_32\lib\tools.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\wlp\clients\restConnector.j
ar 
    -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/IBM/WebSphere/wlp/usr/servers/monitoringServe
r/resources/security/key.jks 
    -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password 
    -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks 
    -J-Duser.language=en
```

I can see ThreadPoolStats and ServletStats. For SessionStats or ConnectionPoolStats your application actually **needs to use the feature** (e.g. session or connection to db) to be visible in jconsole and have mbean.

Comment: Thank you for writing this: "For SessionStats or ConnectionPoolStats your application actually needs to use the feature (e.g. session or connection to db) to be visible in jconsole and have mbean."   It was totally lost on me, and I've been trying to build instrumentation around it. :-)